# Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses")

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

Why do I get this error while fetching data from the Fire store. Fire store works fine with no issue with the Firebase service. I get data using Postman. I just want to get a Fire store collection using an access token.

##### Code

```java
private static  FirestoreDb GetFirestoreDb()
{
    var builder = new FirestoreDbBuilder();
    builder.ProjectId = "ProjectId";
    //Get From https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken Api
    string oauthToken = "AccessToken";
    ITokenAccess credential = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(oauthToken);
    builder.TokenAccessMethod = credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync;

    return builder.Build();
}

private static async void GetDataFromFireStore()
{
    try
    {
        var db =  GetFirestoreDb();
        CollectionReference collectionRef = db.Collection("windows_test");

        // Perform a query and retrieve documents
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await collectionRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(querySnapshot);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exp);
    }
}
```

##### Exception

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1686227565.417000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":5397,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1686227565.417000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\pick_first\pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}")
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.ClientResponseStream`2.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext() in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/ClientResponseStream.cs:line 59
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.AsyncResponseStream`1.<MoveNextAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in /_/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/AsyncResponseStream.cs:line 71
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<<ForEachAsync>g__Core|295_0>d`1.MoveNext() in d:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Linq.Async\System\Linq\Operators\ForEach.cs:line 31
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<<ForEachAsync>g__Core|295_0>d`1.MoveNext() in d:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Linq.Async\System\Linq\Operators\ForEach.cs:line 31
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.<GetSnapshotAsync>d__62.MoveNext() in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Query.cs:line 738
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FreibaseLibraryOld.Program.<GetDataFromFireStore>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\osama.nasir\source\repos\FreibaseLibraryOld\FreibaseLibraryOld\Program.cs:line 36
```

**Note:** Please don't suggest a Firebase Admin SDK method. It's a client side application. I didn't use a Firebase `credentials.json` file.

Comment: You are sending an HTTP Request and should get an HTTP Response with a Status Code which is normally 200 OK.  There is no status code which probably means the connection never completed.  So either the URI is bad or TLS (establish a secure encrypted connection) failed. When TLS fails you do not get a response.

Comment: You're making your life more difficult by not using Application Default Credentials as recommended in Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest). Many of Google's client libraries now use gRPC to connect with backends. I suspect (don't know) that, by using a `builder`, you're going to also have to (re)specify the endpoint for the service (`firestore.googleapis.com:443`). I'm not very familiar with the .NET SDKs.